# How to color Linux terminal foreground and background text

Tags: linux, colors, terminal, command-prompt

I am working on a Linux terminal. The terminal foreground and background colors are hard to look at.

Is there a way to change the terminal prompt colors and keep the commands (ls) at the same colors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How to color the command prompt in the terminal in Linux. This will give you a colored command line and everything else is one color.

```
$ export PS1='\[\033[00;35m\]\u\[\033[00m\]@\[\033[00;35m\]\H\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[00;33m\]\W\[\033[00m\] \$\[\033[00;34m '
```

If you want to make this change permanent, add the command to your `/home/yourusername/.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) in your program output. And if you are coding the terminal emulator, you should make it *understand* those *ANSI escape codes*.